# Android: Changing height for newline in Spannable String does not work

Tags: android, spannablestring

Actually Im trying to increase the line space between text in a Spannable string. Then I want to do it by increasing the span size of the newline character. But it seems the 2nd new line is not affected.

At first i use 'a' as the delimiter to show that the code works.

```
private fun getCenterSpannableText() : SpannableString {
    val currency = "Currency"
    val total = "Total"
    val subtitle = "Subtitle"
    val delimiter = "\n"
    val finalStr = "$currency$delimiter$total$delimiter$subtitle"

    val currencyIndex = finalStr.indexOf(currency)
    val totalIndex = finalStr.indexOf(total)
    val subtitleIndex = finalStr.indexOf(subtitle)

    val s = SpannableString(finalStr)
    s.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan(1.4f), currencyIndex, currency.length, 0)
    s.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextUtil.instance.getColor(R.color.colorGrey5)), currencyIndex, currency.length, 0)

    s.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan(1.8f), totalIndex, totalIndex + total.length, 0)
    s.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextUtil.instance.getColor(R.color.colorGrey5)), totalIndex, totalIndex + total.length, 0)

    s.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan(1f), subtitleIndex, subtitleIndex + subtitle.length, 0)
    s.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextUtil.instance.getColor(R.color.colorGrey2)), subtitleIndex, subtitleIndex + subtitle.length, 0)

    //make the \n have bigger fonts
    s.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan(2.5f), currencyIndex + currency.length, currencyIndex + currency.length + delimiter.length, 0)
    s.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan(2.5f), totalIndex + total.length , totalIndex + total.length + delimiter.length, 0)

    return s
}
```

Output is this:

[image]

Then I change the delimiter to "\n", it does not look right:

[image]

Im running it on API24 Emulator

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is this:

```
Currency\n
Total\n
Subtitle
```

In which case you'd actually want this:

```
Currency\n
Total\n
Subtitle\n
```

EDIT:
That means you might want to try change your code to

```
val finalStr = "$currency$delimiter$total$delimiter$subtitle$delimiter"
```

Comment: why you would think that I want to do that? I want all 3 values to be on separate lines

Comment: You want bigger line spacing between Total and Subtitle, do you not? Did you try doing what I suggested and it failed or is copy pasting one line of code more work than trying to explain it again?
EDIT: My bad, going to edit the answer. It should be on separate lines now.

Comment: adding a newline at the last makes better results now. Then I need to add another s.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan()...) for the last new line and play round the values for the best results. But I dont get it why need to last one at the last. Thanks btw

Comment: If you look at the code segments in my answer, they should be quite descriptive in what is happening. The \n character determines where the line ends, so from that point text continues on a new line (hence "newline" character). Your problem dwells in the fact that the \n character itself remains on that first line. That means the span you're applying to \n is applied to "Currency\n", "Total\n" but not "Subtitle".